# In Jinja2, how should an extension add custom filters?

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm studying the code of **jinja2.ext.InternationalizationExtension** provided with Jinja2.

I know that tags can be added via the **tags** attribute; Jinja2 template parser will relinquish control and call user code when one of those strings is the first token in a {% %} block.

```
class InternationalizationExtension(Extension):
   """This extension adds gettext support to Jinja2."""
    tags = set(['trans'])
```

I learned from the code that an extension can add attributes to the environment by calling **Environment.extend**; for **jinja2.ext.InternationalizationExtension** this is done in the **__init__** method:

```
def __init__(self, environment):
    Extension.__init__(self, environment)
    environment.globals['_'] = _gettext_alias
    environment.extend(
        install_gettext_translations=self._install,
        install_null_translations=self._install_null,
        install_gettext_callables=self._install_callables,
        uninstall_gettext_translations=self._uninstall,
        extract_translations=self._extract,
        newstyle_gettext=False
    )
```

I know that custom filters are added by registering functions into **Environment.filters**:

```
def datetimeformat(value, format='%H:%M / %d-%m-%Y'):
    return value.strftime(format)
environment.filters['datetimeformat'] = datetimeformat
```

The questions are:

- Is it recommended that an extensions adds new filters, and not only tags and attributes to the environment? (The [documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/extensions/) suggests that this should be common practice)
- Where in the extension subclass should this be done? In **__init__** a reference to the environment is available, so in principle the above code could be put in the **__init__** method.
- Is it conceptually ok to do such thing in **__init__**? I personally don't like to alter objects states from within other objects' constructors, but in Jinja2 seems idiomatic enough to make it to an official extension (I'm talking about altering **Environment.globals** and calling **Environment.extend** from **InternationalizationExtension.__init__**).

## Edit

A pattern to *at least* package filters nicely into a Python module. However this `install` function cannot be invoked from within a template (say, via a custom `CallBlock` created using an extension), because the environment should not be edited after the template has been instantiated.

```
def greet(value):
    return "Hello %s!" % value

def curse(value):
    return "Curse you, %s!" % value

def ohno(value):
    return "Oh, No! %s!" % value

def install(env):
    env.filters['greet'] = greet
    env.filters['curse'] = curse
    env.filters['ohno'] = ohno
```

Comment: Have you found a decent solution? I am looking to provide Jinja filters in a separate file/package, and I am hoping to make them easily available, say via something like `import my_custom_filters` if possible.

Comment: If what you want is something similar to Django's {% load %} statement, which offers an unified way to load custom template tags and filters from within a template, at runtime, well, to the best of my knowledge this is not doable in Jinja, because the environment must contain the filters *before* the template is instantiated. In my original question I also highlight that Jinja doesn't really seem to consider custom filters as first-class members of an extension, and doesn't provide a framework/guideline to load a bunch of them with a single istruction (even from within Python code).

Comment: Your best bet is to make them available easily *at least* from Python code. Put your filters in a module and then provide an install function that loads those filters in an environment specified as a parameter. Check my updated answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it recommended that an extensions adds new filters, and not only tags and attributes to the environment?

Only if you need them. Otherwise, why overcomplicate your code? Filters are a very common use case for writing or extending other extensions, and the author most likely put that in there because they expect this to happen.

> Where in the extension subclass should this be done?

It has to be done at call time, so if you don't directly put it in the **__init__** you'll need to put it in a helper method called through **__init__**.

> Is it conceptually ok to do such thing in **__init__**?

It's perfectly fine, so long as other users of your code can understand what it's doing. The simplest solution is usually the best.

Comment: Indeed, environment modifications _have_ to be done during `__init__`, because (from the Jinja 2.11.x docs): "Extensions are added to the Jinja environment at creation time. Once the environment is created additional extensions cannot be added. To add an extension pass a list of extension classes or import paths to the extensions parameter of the Environment constructor." Each enabled extension's `__init__` will be called during the environment's _own_ `__init__`, and once everything's been constructed the window to extend the environment closes.